# How to save user input in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm writing my first vb.net application. It basically copies files from a user input source location to another user input destination location. I want to add a button that saves the user input in both the source location and destination location.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox1.Text = ""
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    Else TextBox1.Text = ""

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    TextBox2.Text = ""
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox2.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    Else TextBox2.Text = ""

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


    Me.Refresh()
    Label1.Text = "Working... Please do not close this window. Even if says not responding  "

    Dim location As String
    Dim locationsave As String

    location = TextBox1.Text
    locationsave = TextBox2.Text
    Try

        Me.Refresh()
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(location, locationsave, True)
        Label1.Text = "Completed! Backed up to: " & locationsave

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Either your source location or destination location does not exist! Please check them and try again.", "Oops!")

    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The right way to ask question here is to show some code.

Comment: "Source location" usually means the location that you are copying *from*. Why does your program need to save the user input to both the source location and the destination location? Isn't it already saved at the source location?

Comment: @AryanFirouzian Sorry first time poster, I edited the post to include the entire code.

Comment: @JohnWu I want the user to be able to input the location of the file that needs backed up and where they want the file to be copied to, they can do that now, But I would like to allow them to save their own input. Because once they close the application it clears the textbox.

Comment: It is not C# btw

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are dealing with simple text files. This code will work for you but it can be improved.

```
        //Path of input file, i.e. "test.txt"
        string inputLocation = "Input file location";
        //destination file location
        string destinationLocation = "Output file location";
        //value user wants to add to file.
        string userInput = "some user input";


        //Create a stream reader, this will read the input file
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputLocation);
        //Save the file's contents to a variable
        string fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //close the stream reader, otherwise you wont be able to write to the file
        sr.Close();

        //Open a stream writer to append the user input to the original file
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(inputLocation,true);
        //Append the user inout to the file
        sw.WriteLine(userInput);
        //close the file
        sw.Close();

        //Open a stream writer to write the new file
        sw = new StreamWriter(destinationLocation,false);
        //add the original file contents to the new file
        sw.WriteLine(fileContents);
        //add the user input to the new file
        sw.WriteLine(userInput);
        //close the new file
        sw.Close();
```

Some more reading:

- https://csharp-station.com/Article/Index/ReadWriteTextFile
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff0d0f/streamreader-and-streamwriter-in-C-Sharp-net/